# How can I embed an echo statmtement inside another?

Tags: php, html

this is the line that is not working (the value)

```
echo '<form method = "post" action = "../bidPlaced.php" >';
echo '<input type = "text" name = "furnitureId" value="<?php echo $item->getFurnitureId()?>" hidden>';
echo '<input type = "number" class="form-control bg-light" name = "bidAmount" placeholder = "Bid Amount" required >';
echo '<input type = "submit" class="btn btn-dark" name = "submit" value = "PLACE BID" >';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: the Value of furnitureId

Comment: you dont need to do that. you can just concat your variable with the echo or inside him

Comment: I am new new to php, so can you please show me how to contact it with the echo

Comment: `echo '<input type = "text" name = "furnitureId" value="' . $item->getFurnitureId() . '" hidden>';`